# Error installing Mysql and connect to Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I try to connect MySQL on my django project, but I still have error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

For more information I use Fedora 31, virtual env in python3.7.7, and when I try to install Mysql
pip3 install mysql, mysql-python, pymysql...

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-h723r47l/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-h723r47l/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-jqp83cjt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/carthur/.local/include/python3.7m/mysqlclient
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-h723r47l/mysqlclient/
Complete output (31 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
MySQLdb/_mysql.c:38:10: erreur fatale: Python.h : No such file or directory
38 | #include "Python.h"
| ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminée.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-h723r47l/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-h723r47l/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-jqp83cjt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/carthur/.local/include/python3.7m/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

If you have any idea for helping me, I take it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem of C files compilation.

I should do :

```
sudo dnf install python3-devel
```

and for python2 :

```
sudo dnf install python2-devel
```

Thanks to Django_learn reddit and THICC_DICC_PRICC for the help.